# Copying file from PC to VPC?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-pc, vpc

I'm running VPC 2007 and the OS is windows 3.1 I need to copy a C++ compiler from my real computer to the virtual one. How do I do this, it doesn't seem to read the .iso that I made. I don't have a floppy drive since I'm using a laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag files from your PC and drop them on the VPC.  Windows 3.1 supported drag & drop, so (in principle) this should work.

Comment: Does VPC provide "Guest Additions" (the drivers that support things like drag-n-drop from host to guest) for Win 3.1? I didn't think they did (or they dropped it at some point over the last couple years).

Answer (score 2):

In VPC 2007, click on the yellow folder in the lower left hand corner of the frame around your guest OS. This will let you map a folder on the host to a drive letter on the guest. Then in the guest you can access the mapped drive as if it were a network drive.